# can't upload app to app store with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, openframeworks

I'm trying to upload an app i'm developing for iPads through xcode

I believe i've set everything up correctly but i'm getting this error in xcode when I click "Upload to app store" in the archive feature.

"Store submission configuration cannot be requested. Bundle ID not found."

I have the same bundle id in all of:
- xcode target settings
- ios app id in the developer.apple.com page
- itunes connect->my apps page

code signing identity is set to my distribution profile

signing certificate is set to my iPhone developer profile

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you created app on itunes connect ?

Comment: yes I have, it has the same bundle id as I am using on my apple developer page and in xcode

Comment: try to upload app through application loader.also you need your distribution provisioning with your distribution certificate. also use iphone distribution certificate rahter than iphone developer.

Comment: I get this error when I try with application loader: "
You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request."

Comment: you may getting this error when free space in my mac hard disk was low

Comment: no plenty of hard drive space...

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was caused by the value of the setting for the key "Executable File" in the **info.plist**

I used a hard coded String before - after changing this to

```
$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
```

the problem was fixed.

It should look like this:

[image: Correct setting for Executable file]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you get errors like this when uploading to iTunes, if everything is correct, if you just try again in a few hours it may work ok. If not, then make sure your provisioning profile is all correct. 
Also try doing a Product->Clean then create a new archive and try to upload that one.